# Where to store a text file read by a java class; java class then used in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

I wrote a java class that has a constructor that reads a text file. I am attempting to use this class in a JSP file. When i try running the JSP it gives me this error message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/DrivingTest.txt (No such file or directory)
```

I changed the file path in the class to /WEB-INF/DrivingTest.txt.

My question is, where do i store this text file so it can be read by the java class and then be accessed in the JSP? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should post the code where you try to open the file...

Answer (score 0):

Place DrivingTest.txt in the same package in which your Java Class Located.
and use just "DrivingTest.txt" in you java class.

Comment: That's not right. You have to deal with context in JSP or Servlets. This is not the same as a console Java program.

Answer (score 0):

Place your DrivingTest.txt file in the same package where your java file is (in my code Test Class) and

Try this...

```
public class Test {
String message;
public Test() throws IOException{
    File path=(new File(Test.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath())).getParentFile();
    File txtfile=new File(path,"DrivingTest.txt");
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txtfile));
    message=br.readLine();
    br.close();

}
```

after this you can access your message string int your jsp.
!!!!!!!!!must reDeploy your Web Application!!!!!!!!!